# mpeg-4 format not working in VideoView

Tags: android, format, media, android-videoview

I'm using a videoview to show a movie (which works on an htc desire). But this fails on the htc wildfire. I don't get a stacktrace, just android itself telling me it cannot play this movie. I thought mpeg-4 was generally working on android? I'm programming for api level 4. Does someone know why this format isn't accepted and which formats work?

Comment: I have a similar problem with an AVI that a desire can play, but an lg can't

Comment: I ended up using the native youtube player. Stupid because you can't really embed it in your application. But I think there is no other way to make a movie work on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

MPEG4 is supported on Android when it is contained in the following container formats- .mp4, .3gp and .ts. I think you are trying to play a mpeg4 media content in .avi which is not supported.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) is a list of all the media formats supported by Android.

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not be your problem's solution but maybe it will help someone who lands here by search.

I couldn't get Android's VideoView from API example to play any file, but it was a mistake on my part.

1. I've type path from the root, example **/videoFileName.mp4** and I should have type it with sdcard in between like **/sdcard/videoFileName.mp4**

**2. My Sony Ercisson Xperia Arc was connected as a usb mass device storage at the same time I was running my app through adb, so internal sd card was unmounted and file could not be found. I've discovered this when I tryed same code on Samsung Galaxy S which behaves differently when connected.**

Maybe the bolded part is your problem?